# Convertir None a valor numérico 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenemos un problema que viene dado porque Python utiliza `None` en vez de valor `0` y queremos saber como convertirlo a entero (0). Básicamente el problema es que, al salir valor `None` en algunos casos, luego no podemos ordenar usando `sorted` porque son tipos de datos heterogéneos (`int` y `None`).

```
puntuados = [[calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva] #Calcula el fitness de cada individuo, y lo guarda en pares ordenados de la forma (5 , [1,2,1,1,4,1,8,9,4,1])

def takeSecond(puntuados):
    return puntuados[0]
puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=takeSecond) [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
poblacionNueva = puntuados
print(poblacionNueva)

poblacionV2 = [x[1] for x in poblacionNueva]
print(poblacionV2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Carlos una pregunta, ¿el primer elemento solo puede ser `None` o un entero positivo?. Lo digo porque se puede simplificar algo más de ser así.

Comment: Un entero positivo incluyendo 0 @FJSevilla

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear una nueva lista usando compresión de listas y la sintaxis propia del operador ternario:

```
lista = [[None, [114, 20, 471, 445, 14]],
         [1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
         [None, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]
        ]

lista2 = [[0, sl[1]] if sl[0] == None else sl for sl in lista]
```

Otra opción es hacerlo en un `for` simplemente sobre la propia lista:

```
for sublista in lista:
    if sublista[0] == None:
        sublista[0] = 0
```

Si solo tienes valores `None` y enteros como primer elemento (o quieres sustituir todos los valores evaluados como `False` por un 0) puedes valerte del operador `or` y hacer simplemente:

```
for sublista in lista:
    sublista[0] = sublista[0] or 0
```

La misma idea puede ser aplicada para compresión de listas:

```
lista2 = [[sl[0] or 0, sl[1]] for sl in lista]
```

El `for` a diferencia de la lista por compresión no te crea una lista nueva, modifica la que tienes in-place.

**Salida:**

> ```
> [[0, [114, 20, 471, 445, 14]],
>  [1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
>  [0, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]]
> ```

Si quieres ordenar sin perder los valores `None` y tomandolos como si fueran 0, puedes valerte del argumento `key` de `sorted`:

```
ordenada = sorted(lista, key = lambda sl: (sl[0] or 0, sl[1]))
```

Esto trata a `None` (en realidad cualquier valor evaluado como `False` por Python) como si fuera un 0 a la hora de ordenar pero los valores `None` siguen en la lista:

```
lista = [[None, [114, 20, 471, 445, 14]],
         [1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
         [0, [110, 20, 471, 445, 14]],
         [None, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]
        ]

ordenada = sorted(lista, key = lambda sl: (sl[0] or 0, sl[1]))
```

**Salida:**

> ```
>  [[None, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]],
>   [0, [110, 20, 471, 445, 14]],
>   [None, [114, 20, 471, 445, 14]],
>   [1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]]
> ```